# Autowiring multiple SimpleJobLaunchers

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a class which I want to run jobs from asynchronously. To do this I have the following code:

```
@Resource
private SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;

@PostConstruct
public void initLauncher(){
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
}
```

However, there is a situation where I need to do this synchronously. So, what I have done is added the following variable:

```
@Resource
private SimpleJobLauncher synchronousJobLauncher;
```

Which I hoped wouldn't have the `taskExecutor` on it making it synchronous. I then pass the `synchronousJobLauncher` to the places where I want to do things synchronously. However, using the `synchronousJobLauncher` gives me the same error as when I use the asynchronous one which leads me to believe that you cannot autowire the same variable twice like I am trying to do. If I do not do the `@PostConstruct` part of the code, the synchronous part works like I expect but not the asynchronous part, even though they use, what I think are, different job launchers.

Any ideas? I have tried using the `@Resource` annotation instead of `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used SimpleJobLaunchers, but normally, in Spring I always used the `@Async` annotation, which make asynchronous execution quite simple. All you have to do is add this annotation, `@EnableAsync` in any configuration file, just like the one below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { ... }
```

Now, is all about adding the `@Async` to any method that will run asynchronously.

```
@Component
class AsyncTask {

     @Async
     public Future<String> run() throws InterruptedException {
        return new AsyncResult<String>("return value");
     }
}
```

And if you want to wait for the result, you can do the following.

```
public void callAsyncTask() {
    try {
        Future<String> future =  asyncTask.run();
        // Do some other things while the async task is running.
        // future.get() will block the function and wait for the result.
        String asyncResult = future.get();
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Do something else.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. I know is not directly what you were asking for, but maybe this solution can facilitate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two job launchers (one synchronous and one asynchronous) then inject the one you want using a qualifier. By default, the `SimpleJobLauncher` uses a synchronous task executor, so you need to configure a task executor only for the asynchronous one. Here is an example:

```
@Bean
public SimpleJobLauncher synchronousJobLauncher() {
    return new SimpleJobLauncher();
}

@Bean
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
}

@Bean
public SimpleJobLauncher asynchronousJobLauncher() {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
    return jobLauncher;
}
```

Then, inject the job launcher you want with a `@Qualifier("synchronousJobLauncher")` or `@Qualifier("asynchronousJobLauncher")` according to your needs.

Hope this helps.